# Adding DataRow items from collection of values

Tags: c#, collections, datatable, datarow

I am trying to create a DataRow which gets some values from hard-coded strings or string variables, and the rest of the values from a collection's values, `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, double>.ValueCollection` to be specific. In my attempt below, I'm casting to an array but that doesn't work.

```
DataTable source = new DataTable();

foreach (string sample in GridSource.SampleName)
{
    SampleDictionaries sd = GridSource.Data.Where(x => GridSource.Data.IndexOf(x) == GridSource.SampleName.IndexOf(sample)).First();
    source.Rows.Add(sample, "Average", sd.Avg.Values.ToArray());
    source.Rows.Add("", "Std. Deviation", sd.StdDev.Values.ToArray());
}
```

The code above produces this: 
[image]

I understand what is happening here. My question is this: is there an easy way to tell the DataRow "Fill the remaining column values with this collection," or am I going to have to come up with some loop to do it?

Comment: I think `.Add(new object[] { sample, "Average" }.Concat(sd.Avg.Values.Cast<object>().ToArray());` should work, u might not need the `Cast` not sure

Comment: @KMoussa ahh man that looks like good code but it didn't quite do it. I'm betting that is close to what I need. I'll keep tinkering with it and see what I can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer, with help from KMoussa!

```
source.Rows.Add(new object[] { "", "Std. Deviation"}.Concat(sd.StdDev.Values.Cast<object>().ToArray()).ToArray());
```

Very similar to what he recommended, but it was missing a second cast to array at the end.

Answer (score 2):

what you can do is create the row from the datatable.NewRow() method.  Then you can have the items array of the row equal an array of data:

```
DataTable source = new DataTable();

foreach (string sample in GridSource.SampleName)
{
    DataRow temp = source.NewRow();
    SampleDictionaries sd = GridSource.Data.Where(x => GridSource.Data.IndexOf(x) == GridSource.SampleName.IndexOf(sample)).First();
    temp.ItemArray = new object[]{sample, "Average"}.Concat(sd.Avg.Values.ToArray());
    source.Rows.Add(temp);
    temp = source.NewRow();
    temp.ItemArray = new object[]{"", "Std. Deviation".Concat(sd.StdDev.Values.ToArray());
}
```